# Image.file is not supported on Flutter Web. How to get image from gallery/camera for the Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image-picker

I get the error below while running the Flutter app on the Chrome web browser.
I picked an Image from the gallery:

```
  Future getImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) {
        return;
      }
      final imageTemp = XFile(image.path);
      setState(() => this._userImage = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      e.stacktrace;
    }
  }
```

Code:

```
  dynamic getUserImage() {
    if (_userImage?.path == null) {
      return const Icon(
        Icons.person,
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: 54,
      );
    } else {
      return Image.file(File(_userImage!.path));
    }
  }
```

Image:

[image]

What should I use or change to pick an image from the Web gallery or Camera?

Answer (score 7):

Try [Image.network(image.path)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) instead as browser doesn't support to access user's file system.

> Since Web Browsers don't offer direct access to their users' file system, this plugin provides a PickedFile abstraction to make access uniform across platforms.

See [Limitations on the web platform](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web#limitations-on-the-web-platform) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter web is not support File (from dart.io).

There for I just make your method more advance which can used in flutter web ( also Android and IOS ).

After picking successfully image from gallery/Camera we convert into Uint8List.

And then we can display image using Image.memory();

**Pick from Gallery**

```
Future<Uint8List?> galleryImagePicker() async {
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  XFile? file = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: 90,
  );

  if (file != null) return await file.readAsBytes(); // convert into Uint8List.
  return null;
}
```

**Pick from Camera**

```
Future<Uint8List?> cameraImagePicker() async {

  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? file = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
    imageQuality: 90,
  );

  if (file != null) return await file.readAsBytes(); // convert into Uint8List.
  return null;
}
```

**Show Sample Code**

```
 // veriable declare 
 Uint8List? registrationImage; // import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

            onTap: () async {
              final Uint8List? image = await galleryImagePicker();

              if (image != null) {
                registrationImage = image;
                setState(() {});
              }
            },

 // And then Display Image 
  
      Image.memory (
                   registrationImage!,
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
               ),
```

***Hope this will help you ! Thank You***

Answer (score 0):

Try [Web Image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web) or check
web support for the package you are using [Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web)